# "Cannot open file xxx for writing"

Tags: iis, expression-web, microsoft-expression-web

Using Microsoft Expression Web 4 to revise our intranet. I had to enable .shtml on the IIS server in order to be able to use server-side pages.  Sorry, I'm a newbie and had to somehow make it work on a tight deadline.  There' may be better ways of doing this and better, more up-to-date program than Expression, but this is the situation now...
So, I can edit the website just fine. In fact, I'm done and published it etc. Works great.
The problem is, another person who also was able to edit the same Intranet website, now can't do it. She has the same software, but it's getting an error, "Cannot open file XXX for writing" where XXX is any of the .html or .shtml pages, old ones or new ones.  She just can't edit any of them.  She started getting the error as soon as I was done publishing the changes (removed Flash and replace the main menu with a shared .html file called into every page, like <--#include file "\menu.html"-->) The files open OK, the shared menu is there, etc., and she makes the changes, but when she clicks **Save**, that's when she gets the error.
Any ideas as to what may be causing the problem?
I already had her try to edit one of the old pages I replaced. She can't edit those either.

Comment: Problem was one of permissions.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a problem caused by permissions. Find the folder where the file is located, right-click on it, check Properties -> Security, and ensure that the permissions of the two accounts are the same.